# assertXpathCount() returning 0 while using Selenium RC

Tags: xpath, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

I am trying to use `assertXpathCount()` to get the number of rows available in a table.

I am using the Xpath given by the browser of the `<tr>` element. But still I am getting 0 as output.

Are there any special things that I need to keep in mind?

Comment: What happens if you try to wait for a second there? This kind of problems is usually tied with timing and you need to wait for the elements to appear.

Answer (score 0):

One guess

- install [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) and [Firefinder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firefinder-for-firebug/)
- Open your test site with the table you want to verify via Selenium RC
- When page is loaded, insert the xpath you are using into firefinder
- see how many results you get

In nutshell: I have been having similar issues, because I have been stupid and did something wrong to the Xpath used to find element(s). This way you can verify the xpath. It can be, that it really shows zero elements found and thats right because of wrong Xpath provided...

And better idea: If you switch to Webdriver aprroach, you can use command `findElements` which will return you `List` of all elements found. Then by calling function `getLength()` on that list, you have number of elements found

Comment: I copied the xpath from firefox ( inspect with firebug-copy xpath) and pasted it to firefinder, but Firefinder did not found any object for that. and also the same xpath works fine when used in assertxpathcount() in IDE but when i copy paste the ide assertxpathcount()command with xpath in it to RC, it stops working.

Comment: If you heard explosion, that was my head ... Sorry man, but the above solution I could come up with...

Comment: ya.. i guess there is some problem.. is it possible that a command with an xpath works in IDE and when used with same xpath in RC, does not work?

Comment: To be honest - I use webdriver approach. And it never happened to me. Actually, I always use xpath generated by IDE... And it always worked (If I properly copypasted it :) ). Thats why my answer is only idea I have.

Comment: i am also just copy pasting the XPath generated by IDE/Firefox. but i dont know what is happening....i will try to save the test case in ide as java file and then import it in eclilpse for RC.. may be there is some problem with copy paste...

Answer (score 0):

Try finding locator for the first row of table and confirm that it is present on the page like

```
\\some id or name\blah-blah\table\tr
```

Then keep the same locator in getXpathCount.It would give you correct result.If you still get the result as 0 then write your own function for getting xpath count using loops or whatever you like.Thats what I do when I face such problems.